# Do not show child pages within a file page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, pages, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I have a CPT created, in my CPT file page the father pages and daughter pages are shown.

```
Books of science
  Book 1
  Book 2

Books of science fiction
  Book 1
  Book 2
```

In my case I don't want it to be like that, since I want to show the daughter pages only inside the father page.

How can I make the page file only show the father pages and not the daughters?

This is my CPT file template currently:

```
<?php

//* Force full-width-content layout
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' );

remove_action('genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop');

//* New loop
add_action('genesis_loop', 'b_custom_loop');
function b_custom_loop() {
  global $wp_query;

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'b_books',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => 10
  );

  genesis_custom_loop( $args );
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You're going to need to share the code you're using to display what you already have.

Comment: Hi Jacob, I just updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can use `post_parent` parameter for your query. 
Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

This will change your query to:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'b_books',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_parent' => 0
);

genesis_custom_loop( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you Aniruddha!